# Strictly upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

For reasons beyond my control I need to upgrade a 14.04 release to 16.04 release and no further. Is this possible?

Im sure that sudo apt-get dist-upgrade will just update to the latest.

Comment: a `do-release-upgrade` will upgrade to to 16.04.  The upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 isn't open yet (but will be in a few days), though this doesn't matter, the upgrade path is LTS to LTS; you need to make two jumps to go from 14.04 to 18.04 (first goes only to 16.04 LTS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `do-release-upgrade` from a LTS release will upgrade you to the next LTS release, ie. from 14.04 LTS you'll only go to 16.04 LTS.

As of this moment, the path from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS isn't open yet (*it will be in a few days; 18.04.1 is on 2nd RC...), but this doesn't matter; to jump from 14.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS requires two jumps, the first being to the next LTS which is 16.04 LTS.

As @pomsky suggested, have a look at [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) which covers 'release-upgrading' for more upgrade info.

*Also note: `apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't jump you to the next release; unless you modify your sources to include a later release. It does the `apt-get upgrade` but missing fewer updates, from `man apt-get` is the following*

> dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also
>   intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of
>   packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it
>   will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of
>   less important ones if necessary.

Comment: Is your first sentence correct? I think if you upgrade from 14.04 you will get 16.04.

Comment: Much thanks to @OrganicMarble for correcting my unintended horrific typo..